# discrepancy between function result and regular execution without function call in solving easy sudoku

Tags: python, sudoku

hello I am trying to solve easy breezy sudoku problem (no need for guessing) by narrowing down the available moves. In the execution, my solution without defining function solved the sudoku problem in less than a second. But when I define the same process in the function and try to execute the function, it takes million time to produce the result. is there anyone who know why this happen?

```
grid,val={'1':[],'2':[],'3':[],'4':[],'5':[],'6':[],'7':[],'8':[],'9':[]},[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
for i in range(9):
    for j in range(9):
        if 0<=i<3 and 0<=j<3:
            grid['1'].append([i,j])
        elif 0<=i<3 and 3<=j<6:
            grid['2'].append([i,j])
        elif 0<=i<3 and 6<=j<9:
            grid['3'].append([i,j])
        elif 3<=i<6 and 0<=j<3:
            grid['4'].append([i,j])
        elif 3<=i<6 and 3<=j<6:
            grid['5'].append([i,j])
        elif 3<=i<6 and 6<=j<9:
            grid['6'].append([i,j])
        elif 6<=i<9 and 0<=j<3:
            grid['7'].append([i,j])
        elif 6<=i<9 and 3<=j<6:
            grid['8'].append([i,j])
        else:
            grid['9'].append([i,j])
class node():
    def __init__(self,v,h):
        self.v=v
        self.h=h
        if 0<=i<3 and 0<=j<3:
            self.g='1'
        elif 0<=i<3 and 3<=j<6:
            self.g='2'
        elif 0<=i<3 and 6<=j<9:
            self.g='3'
        elif 3<=i<6 and 0<=j<3:
            self.g='4'
        elif 3<=i<6 and 3<=j<6:
            self.g='5'
        elif 3<=i<6 and 6<=j<9:
            self.g='6'
        elif 6<=i<9 and 0<=j<3:
            self.g='7'
        elif 6<=i<9 and 3<=j<6:
            self.g='8'
        else:
            self.g='9'
        self.choice=[]
        self.free=len(self.choice)
        self.value=0
    def __lt__(self,other):
        return self.free<other.free
    def __eq__(self,other):
        return self.free==other.free
    def get_avail(self,sud):
        i,j,k=self.v,self.h,self.g
        av=[]
        for x in range(9):
            if sud[x][j].value!=0:
                av.append(sud[x][j].value)
        for y in range(9):
            if sud[i][y].value!=0:
                av.append(sud[i][y].value)
            for x in range(9):
                v=sud[x][y]
                if v.g==k and v.value!=0:
                    av.append(v.value)
        avail=list(set(val)-set(av))
        if len(avail)==1:
            self.value=avail[0]
        self.choice=avail
        return avail
    def delete(self,sud):
        selff=self.choice
        other=[]
        for i in range(9):
            for j in range(9):
                if i==self.v or self.h==j or self.g==sud[i][j].g:
                    other=other+self.choice
        avail=list(set(selff)-set(other))
        if len(avail)==1:
            self.value=avail[0]
        return avail



def goal(sud):
    for i in range(9):
        for j in range(9):
            if sud[i][j].value==0:
                return False
    return True
def board(sud):
    aa=[]
    for i in range(9):
        aaa=[]
        for j in range(9):
            aaa.append(sud[i][j].value)
        aa.append(aaa)
    return aa
def get_empty(sud):
    aa=[]
    for i in range(9):
        for j in range(9):
            if sud[i][j].value==0:
                aa.append(sud[i][j])
    heapq.heapify(aa)
    return aa



def sudoku(puzzle):
    a=[]
    for i in range(9):
        c=[]
        for j in range(9):
            b=node(i,j)
            if puzzle[i][j]!=0:
                b.value=puzzle[i][j]
            c.append(b)
        a.append(c)
    while goal(a)==False:
        for i in range(9):
            for j in range(9):
                if a[i][j].value==0:
                    a[i][j].get_avail(a)
        for i in range(9):
            for j in range(9):
                if a[i][j].value==0:
                    a[i][j].delete(a)
    return board(a)

def sudoku(puzzle):
    a,new=[],[]
    for i in range(9):
        c=[]
        for j in range(9):
            b=node(i,j)
            if puzzle[i][j]!=0:
                b.value=puzzle[i][j]
            c.append(b)
        a.append(c)
    l=0
    while get_empty(a)!=l:
        l=get_empty(a)
        for i in range(9):
            for j in range(9):
                if a[i][j].value==0:
                    a[i][j].get_avail(a)

        for i in range(9):
            for j in range(9):
                if a[i][j].value==0:
                    a[i][j].delete(a)
    if goal(a):
        return board(a) 
    else:
        new.append(a)               
    while len(new)!=0:
        sud=new.pop(-1)
        em=get_empty(sud)
        s=em.pop()
        cand=s.get_avail(sud)
        for k in range(len(cand)):
            b=copy.deepcopy(sud)
            b[s.v][s.h].value=cand[k]
            l=0
            while len(get_empty(b))!=l:
                l=len(get_empty(b))
                for i in range(9):
                    for j in range(9):
                        if b[i][j].value==0:
                            b[i][j].get_avail(b)

                for i in range(9):
                    for j in range(9):
                        if b[i][j].value==0:
                            b[i][j].delete(b)                        
            new.append(b)                        
            if goal(b):
                return board(b)
    [enter image description here][1]return []
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxmuk.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgK83.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQIla.jpg)

```
puzzle=[[0, 0, 3, 0, 2, 0, 6, 0, 0],
 [9, 0, 0, 3, 0, 5, 0, 0, 1],
 [0, 0, 1, 8, 0, 6, 4, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 8, 1, 0, 2, 9, 0, 0],
 [7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8],
 [0, 0, 6, 7, 0, 8, 2, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 2, 6, 0, 9, 5, 0, 0],
 [8, 0, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 9],
 [0, 0, 5, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 0]]
a,new=[],[]
for i in range(9):
    c=[]
    for j in range(9):
        b=node(i,j)
        if puzzle[i][j]!=0:
            b.value=puzzle[i][j]
        c.append(b)
    a.append(c)
l=0
while get_empty(a)!=l:
    l=get_empty(a)
    for i in range(9):
        for j in range(9):
            if a[i][j].value==0:
                a[i][j].get_avail(a)

    for i in range(9):
        for j in range(9):
            if a[i][j].value==0:
                a[i][j].delete(a)
if goal(a):
    print( board(a) )
else:
    new.append(a)   
while len(new)!=0:
    sud=new.pop(-1)
    em=get_empty(sud)
    s=em.pop()
    cand=s.get_avail(sud)
    for k in range(len(cand)):
        z=copy.deepcopy(sud)
        z[s.v][s.h].value=cand[k]
        l=0
        while len(get_empty(z))!=l:
            l=len(get_empty(z))
            for i in range(9):
                for j in range(9):
                    if z[i][j].value==0:
                        z[i][j].get_avail(z)

            for i in range(9):
                for j in range(9):
                    if z[i][j].value==0:
                        z[i][j].delete(z)                        
        if goal(z):
            print(board(z))
        else:
            new.append(z)
```

Comment: same thing happens in the code with search parts...I put the code part by part and get the solution, but when I use the function it fails and gives empty list. but when I did it parts by parts I got the right answer. I am completely lost

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  To help answer your question I will need some more from you.  1. Can you show code for both cases (defined in your function and not), that part is a bit confusing for me.  2. Copy and paste the text you put in your images into this question.  Stack Overflow can handle the formatting to make things look nice.

Comment: oh okay ill copy and paste the non-function one! sorry for confusion.